# Big O notation - Doubts about the loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, pseudocode

Recently I started reviewing about Big O notation and got a very simple problem.
In fact I'm a little bit confused and if someone can give me a detail of that, will be great.

Looking the pseudocode below:

```
Boolean: ContainsDuplicates(Integer: array[])
    // Loop over all of the array's items except the last one.
    For i = 0 To <largest index> - 1
        // Loop over the items after item i.
        For j = i + 1 To <largest index> N
            // See if these two items are duplicates.
            If (array[i] == array[j]) Then Return True
        Next j
    Next i

    // If we get to this point, there are no duplicates.
    Return False
End ContainsDuplicates
```

I'd like to understand which Big O represent the loop below since the initial value from j is the i + 1:

> For j = i + 1 To  N

Thanks

Comment: Try to visualize. If you draw rows representing the iterations of the inner loop below each other, what do you end up with? What is the (approximate) area of that shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first loop: 1 To N
- second loop: 2 To N
- third loop: 3 To N
  ...
- before last loop: N-2 To N
- last loop: N-1 to N

Do you see any pattern?
It's like doing 1+2+3+...+(N-1)+N

The formulae to achieve this is (N+1)(N)/2

In Big O notation, this is equivalent to N²

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I'm reading a book and there are two different approaches. 
The first one as described below:

```
Boolean: ContainsDuplicates(Integer: array[])
    // Loop over all of the array's items.
    For i = 0 To <largest index>
        For j = 0 To <largest index>
        // See if these two items are duplicates.
        If (i != j) Then
            If (array[i] == array[j]) Then Return True
        End If
        Next j
    Next i

    // If we get to this point, there are no duplicates.
    Return False
    End ContainsDuplicates

and then there is the other shared here as:

Boolean: ContainsDuplicates(Integer: array[])
    // Loop over all of the array's items except the last one.
    For i = 0 To <largest index> - 1
        // Loop over the items after item i.
        For j = i + 1 To <largest index> N
            // See if these two items are duplicates.
            If (array[i] == array[j]) Then Return True
        Next j
    Next i

    // If we get to this point, there are no duplicates.
    Return False
End ContainsDuplicates
```

I guess the both result are the same, i.e, N² right?

Comment: in Big O yes, because Big-O notation only describes asymptotic beahviour. So both , N² and 5N²+8N will both be considered O(N²) even if the second one is slower. In this case, the first one have a complexity of N² while the other have a complexity of (N+1)(N)/2, so even if in Big O, both result are the same, i.e, N², the second one is better